# How to add circular region onto MKMapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkoverlay, mkcircle

I am trying to add a circular region on my MKMapView like the picture below for my current location. I can pin the map with annotations but don't know how to get it to show a circular region like this with a radius and have it shaded.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I figured it out...

Below is how I did it along with code.

Step 1: - Create `MKCircle`

```
MKCircle *circleOverlay = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:zoomLocation radius:300];//radius in meters
```

Step 2: - Set `title` and add to Map Overlays

```
[circleOverlay setTitle:@"Circle1"];

[_mapView addOverlay:circleOverlay];
```

Step 3: - Implement the `mapView:rendererForOverlay:` method in my MapViewDelegate

```
-(MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay{

    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKCircle class]])
    {
        MKCircleRenderer* aRenderer = [[MKCircleRenderer alloc] initWithCircle:(MKCircle *)overlay];

        aRenderer.fillColor = [[UIColor cyanColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
        aRenderer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
        aRenderer.lineWidth = 3;
        return aRenderer;
    }else{
        return nil;
    }
}
```

That was it! Boom! Hope it helps someone in the future! Not sure if this is the best way but it achieve my goal!

Edit: make sure to set your mapView's delegate to self or the required delegate method will not be called.